# Including JSP in HTML

Tags: java, html, jsp

I'm developing a web page, in that page at bottom I have to upload a file. I have code for upload, but that is in JSP. How I can include that JSP in my HTML page?

### index.jsp

```html
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
     pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
 <html>
 <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>File Upload Example in JSP and Servlet - Java web application</title>
</head>

<body> 
    <div>
        <h3> Choose File to Upload in Server </h3>
        <form action="UploadServlet" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="file" name="file" />
            <input type="submit" value="upload" />
        </form>          
    </div>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you reversed the order, you should include `html` in `jsp`.  just create a `jsp` file and put the necessary part of `html` file into `jsp`

Comment: Any specific reasons?why you want to include jsp in html?

Comment: but actually ,this is just an `html` like page, you do not need to suffix it as `.jsp`, just use `.html`

Comment: @Rugal If you dont make .jsp extension then the first line (<%...) will be printed in the browser page

Comment: @JqueryLearner  yeah, hence the poster need to remove some unnecessary code in this file

Comment: BTW - time to update to HTML 5.

Comment: @AndrewThompson I think OP is also using html5 because he uses <!DOCTYPE html ........

Comment: @JqueryLearner  I think the `4.01 Transitional` part of the string suggests otherwise.. ;)

Comment: actually in some div part of my html i want to include dis upload..

Answer (score -1):

You can include an html file in a jsp file but cannot include a jsp file in a html file because html files are not parsed on the server-side (so how will the server know to do the include?) and jsp are (assuming you are using a servlet-container).

Make the main file a JSP, put the snippet in an html file, then include in your DIV by using

```
<div>
   <jsp:include page="snippet.html" />
</div>
```